# i can't use an array in other function?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm writing a program to print a numbers in array then used function to split the array to an odd and even number. I've done this part, then I have to sent each of the odd and even array to another function that calculate the largest number in each array and return the calculated value. It seem there something missing in the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void split();
int largest(int arr[]);

int main() {
  int a[11] = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8, 3, 9, 14, 17};
  printf("the values of the array is :\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }
  split();
  int z = largest(odd);
  printf("the max value in odd array is :%d\n", z);
}

void split() {
  int i, evenNumber = 0, oddNumber = 0;
  int even[11], odd[11];
  int a[11] = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8, 3, 9, 14, 17};
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
      even[evenNumber++] = a[i];
    } else {
      odd[oddNumber++] = a[i];
    }
  }
  printf("\nEven :\n");
  for (i = 0; i < evenNumber; i++) {
    printf("%d ", even[i]);
  }
  printf("\nOdd :\n");
  for (i = 0; i < oddNumber; i++) {
    printf("%d ", odd[i]);
  }
}

int largest(int odd[]) {
  int max;
  max = odd[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    if (max < odd[i]) {
      max = odd[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about pointers so far?

Comment: This isn't even a matter of pointers, there's not `odd` in `main`.

Comment: @DZDomi  no not yet

Comment: @Iluvatar we did't take pointer yet !

Comment: I've always thought pointers should be taught before arrays. Nobody seems to agree with me.

Comment: Well until you pass something that actually exists to `largest` you're not going to get a lot of results.

Comment: @Iluvatar umm sorry but i dont understand you .. i want to take the array from the first function in put it to the mine so that the mine could do the second function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually *can* use arrays in other functions.  However, the problem you are running into is scope.

---

## The Problem

In your `main` function,

```
int main ()
{
    int a[11] = {2,4,5,6,7,1,8,3,9,14,17};

    printf("the values of the array is :\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i<11 ; i++){
         printf("%d ",a[i]);
    } 
    split();

    int z = largest(odd);
    printf("the max value in odd array is :%d\n",z);
}
```

the line `int z = largest(odd);` uses the variable `odd`.  However, `odd` is never defined in `main`.  Rather, `odd` is defined in the scope of `split()`.

It appears you think that because you are calling `split()` in main, that somehow you will able to access `odd` in `main` after you call `split()`.  **This is not true.**  Even though `odd` is defined in `split()`, it is defined *only* in `split()`.  So even though `main` calls `split()`, `odd` is still not defined in `main`.

This is because a variable is limited to the scope in which it is defined.  If a variable is defined in a function (i.e. the function is its scope), it is accessible only within that function, even if that function is used elsewhere.  If you want to use a variable outside of the function in which it is defined, you must somehow "return" that variable from the function.

I strongly recommend reading a tutorial on how "scope" works in C, e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm).

---

## The Solution

You have a two main options:

- Rewrite `split()` to somehow return `odd`.
- Move the contents of `split()` to `main`.  I.e. don't make `split()` a separate function.

Unless you have a specific reason for keeping `split()` as a separate function, I would strongly recommend just moving its contents into `main`.  Otherwise, you will have to pass multiple parameters as references to make `split()` work the way you want it to.

If we move the contents of `split()` into `main` (and make the necessary adjustments to remove duplicate variables), this is what the new code will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int largest(int arr[]);

int main() {
    int a[11] = { 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8, 3, 9, 14, 17 };

    printf("the values of the array is :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    int evenNumber = 0, oddNumber = 0;
    int even[11], odd[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even[evenNumber++] = a[i];
        } else {
            odd[oddNumber++] = a[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\nEven :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < evenNumber; i++) {
        printf("%d ", even[i]);
    }

    printf("\nOdd :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < oddNumber; i++) {
        printf("%d ", odd[i]);
    }

    int z = largest(odd);
    printf("the max value in odd array is :%d\n", z);

}

int largest(int odd[]) {
    int max = odd[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (max < odd[i]) {
            max = odd[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

### One more comment:

Whenever you pass an array to a function, you should always pass the length of the array too.  For example:

```
int largest(int odd[], int len) {
    int max = odd[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (max < odd[i]) {
            max = odd[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

And then you would call `largest(int[], int)` like this:

```
largest(odd, 11);
```

Comment: ok but i have to put 'split()' in separate function but how i can move its contents to 'main' ?

Comment: @asim If you prefer to keep `split()`, then `even` and `odd` should be declared inside `main()` instead of `split()`, and `split()` could be changed to `void split(const int a[], int even[], int odd[], int size)`.  `size` can be determined with the old C idiom of `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`, which determines the number of elements in an array by dividing its size in memory by each element's size in memory; this is better than hard-coding `11`. You would call it as `split(a, even, odd, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));`. If you do this, don't define arrays named `a`, `even`, and `odd` in `split()`.